# BIOS loading screen doesn't show

Tags: bios

I have a single operating system (Ubuntu). When I start my computer, I get a black screen, and after a few seconds, the Ubuntu loading screen, and after that I'm able to use my computer as usual. I do not get the BIOS loading screen. I've tried F2 and F12 (which are the keys used in Toshiba Satellite, my laptop) while the black screen shows to enter BIOS setup, but those don't work.

How do I fix this? I've already reinstalled Ubuntu (not because of this) and the problem still persists, though I doubt that Ubuntu is the problem.

EDIT: My questions is not how to enter the BIOS setup - I know how to do that. The problem is that I don't even get the usual loading screen that says "TOSHIBA" and "Press F12 to enter setup". My computer, on being turned on, directly shows the Ubuntu loading screen

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/180244/how-do-i-enter-bios

Comment: I've already tried that - that's not the problem. I assume that the OP there gets the BIOS screen that shows the laptop model and instructions to enter BIOS setup. I don't even get that.

Comment: The key sequence to enter the BIOS after power up depends on the PC.  What make & model is your PC?  Have you tried reading the manual for your PC?

Comment: Toshiba Satellite, and yes. I've entered the BIOS many times before (mostly to change boot sequence). This is a recent problem

Comment: Again, there is a deeper problem as the screen that says "TOSHIBA" and "Press F12 to enter setup" doesn't even show - my computer directly goes to the Ubuntu loading screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You may have inadvertantly selected a "quick boot", "boot logo" or similar setting**, which replaces the BIOS' normal output with a graphical image and might skip certain checks to make the system boot faster. But I find it hard to see that something like that would have changed without you actively doing anything to the BIOS.

**Removing the CMOS battery, or using a "CLEAR CMOS" jumper on the motherboard** (at least on full-sized motherboards there is usually one that can be set to either "normal" or "clear"/"reset"), would be the first thing I try. You'll lose all BIOS settings, including the system date and time, but once you get into the BIOS setup a "restore to factory defaults" or similar should be all that is needed to bring the settings to reasonable values. Remember to reset the system time afterwards, preferably before booting (some things may be upset when the system time makes sudden jumps of many years). **Note** that since you have a single-boot Linux system the OS may be configured to read the system clock as UTC rather than local time.

Clearing the CMOS memory by any means will usually force you to enter the BIOS setup on the next boot, because then the internal data checksum won't match.

Comment: Thank you! You were right, I had enable 'Fast Boot' and forgotten about it, because I anyway had only one operating system. I didn't know that would skip system checks, so I've disabled it. On Toshiba, if you press and hold F2 _before_ turning your laptop on, it goes to the BIOS setup.

Comment: @asymptotically Exactly what `Fast Boot` mode does varies from system to system, but unless the few additional seconds spent doing the Power-On Self Test (POST) are a major problem for some reason, I tend to set all relevant BIOS settings to "take your time and show what you are doing" values. It doesn't bother me (and less tech-savvy people will just see some text flash by briefly) and it makes diagnostics much easier if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are more ways to open the BIOS, depending on what company developed it. [Have you tried all of these?](http://www.mydigitallife.info/comprehensive-list-of-how-key-to-press-to-access-bios-for-various-oem-and-computer-systems/) (Or at least those by your system's manufacturer

Might be that you somehow disabled the BIOS from showing at boot, and you should be able to re-enable it in the BIOS itself (using whatever key combination, see link above)

Comment: Yes, I've tried them all

Comment: Does your system have PS/2 connections? Sometimes you can only access BIOS using these instead of USB keyboard

Comment: Or have you tried booting with the keyboard unplugged?

Comment: Only my touchpad. It's a laptop

Comment: I'm unabke to even see the BIOS loading screen, which I could just a few weeks back

Comment: And everything else works fine? You didn't notice something like the time being reset or something? You could try clearing CMOS, this might solve your problem. Try removing the battery and power cable and hold the power button for several seconds, that could help

Comment: Nope, everything works fine after the Ubuntu screen comes, none of my settings changed, and everything was smooth: I was able to shut down, restart, hibernate, everything. I've already tried the power thing, but I didn't try CMOS. I'll do that now.

Comment: The above answer solved it, so did yours. Thanks for telling me about CMOS, I didn't know about that and I'm sure that'll come in handy some time

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your battery for a few seconds and then try to reboot your PC. As soon as it starts try to get to the BIOS CP by pressing the BIOS CP buttons. They will likely be ESC, F2, F10 and DEL.

Comment: Already tried - see the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off your laptop then press F2 and hold at the same time power on then show up your bios image then change booting fast to Normal.. That's it.. Good luck

Comment: The selected answer already suggested that, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be something bizarre, mine was apparently a bad HDMI cable. I would not bother to post this, but I never would have found the problem except by accident when I swapped cables with another computer and it would not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem on Fedora and OpenSUSE as well on my Lenovo laptop. The trick is to get the GRUB boot menu to appear before it starts to launch the actual OS.

You can probably adjust a setting in GRUB to always show this menu, but I was able to get to it by pressing `ESC` once at startup after the motherboard's splash screen goes away. If you hold it down or press it many times, it will probably go to the GRUB command line, which you do not want.

If you can't time the press of `ESC` properly, press the key to show the BIOS screen on boot, then hold `ESC`. Once you get to the GRUB command line, type in `exit`, then press enter. It should then go to the BIOS screen.

Once the GRUB menu appears, select "UEFI Boot options" (text may be different), and it should bring up the BIOS screen after rebooting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Better option, this one works for old PCs. MY ORIGINAL!!

1. Get rid of the keyboard for a minute.
2. Then simply start the PC. You must see a screen like this. Observe it.

   [image]

   Read the last line. It is `Press DEL key to enter setup, ESC to skip memory test`.
3. Press <kbd>Del</kbd> to enter the BIOS setup.